# Matlab datenum generation

Tags: matlab, date

I'm using dtstr2dtnummx because that is faster, but I faced a problem, this function is generation a different datenum, or maybe my date format is not correct

> date = {'2011-03-13 23:59:59.100'}
>
> out1 =datenum(date)
>
> out2=dtstr2dtnummx(date,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.SSS')

and the outputs are:

> date =
>
> ```
> '2011-03-13 23:59:59.100'
> ```
>
> out1 =
>
> ```
>       734575.999989583
> ```
>
> out2 =
>
> ```
>       736281.960423495
> ```

I don't know where is the error

**UPDATE**

I found an answer, with the following dateformat I get the same result

> dtstr2dtnummx(date,'YYYY-MM-dd
> HH:mm:ss.SSS')

But I don't know why like this, because I followed [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bspgcx2-1.html#bspgc4m-1) tutorial, but I get the wrong output, If anybody know the answer please share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`datenum` and `dtstr2dtnummx` use different format strings: `datenum` calls `cnv2icudf` to convert "date format tokens to ICU date format tokens" (see `help cnv2icudf`) which are usable with `dtstr2dtnummx`. Note this includes swapping upper- and lowercase for MM (interchanging month and minutes). In other words, you used the documentation for `datenum` to create a format string for `dtstr2dtnummx`, which is undocumented and private.

To get the correct format string to use, you can call

```
cnv2icudf('yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF')
```

resulting in

> ans =
>
> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

which is quite close to the solution you found yourself.

Lesson learned: there is a reason why `dtstr2dtnummx` is a private function - don't call it until you understand the wrapper `datenum` ;-).

BTW, out of curiosity: Did you really profile your code and found `datenum` to be a major culprit?

Comment: Note that your original format string 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.SSS' is a mixture of both formats - milliseconds for `datenum` are 'FFF' while for the private function they are 'SSS'

Comment: I should maybe mention that to be able to call these private functions at all, I copied them from `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\toolbox\matlab\timefun\private\cnv2icudf.m` to my working directory...

Comment: Yes, I copied there the dtstr2dtnummx to :)

Comment: I tested the running time and 1000 conversation it takes between 3.5s and 4s and with dtstr2dtnummx it's take just 0.8s, so that is really big optimization:) because I have a really large database(measurements) 100million rows, so in this case it count the time